# Get the component of a rendered element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, element

Currently, I'm making a modal system with React.
So I have a button in a sidebar and my modal is a div in the body.

I have two component that are rendered in the render function of the main component of my app:

- MyModal
- MyModalOpenButton

Here is what I need:
When the event onClick of the MyModalOpenButton is triggered, I need to execute a function stored in the MyModal component.

So I basically need to store the ref of MyModal in a var.

How can I do this ?

---

Codes:

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";

import { MyModal } from "./component/modal/my-modal";
import { SettingsButtons } from "./component/settings-buttons";
import { CustomComponent } from "./custom-component";

class App extends CustomComponent<{}, {}>{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="sidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            1
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            2
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            3
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <SettingsButtons />
                </div>
                <div className="mainContent">

                </div>
                <footer>TODO</footer>
                <MyModal />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const app: App = ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root")) as App;
```

And

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";

import { CustomComponent } from "./../../custom-component";
import { ButtonComponent } from "./button";

export class MyModalOpenButton extends ButtonComponent<{}, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li id="open-button" onClick={this.onClick}>
                <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </li>
        );
    }
    onClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
        // Should open the modal
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code for your components?

Comment: You might want to have a look at how I implemented callbacks here https://github.com/Frazer/react-meteor-modal/tree/master/demo/lib/jsx   in the ConfirmModal and ControlledConfirmModal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your code, so I can't give you an answer that will match your case specifically, but in general:

```
class MyModal extends React.Component<any, any> {
    public render() {
        ...
    }

    public onButtonClick() {
        ...
    }
}

interface MyModalOpenButtonProps {
    onClick: () => void;
}
class MyModalOpenButton extends React.Component<MyModalOpenButtonProps, any> {
    public render() {
        return <button onClick={ this.props.onClick } />
    }
}

class Main extends React.Component<any, any> {
    private myModal: MyModal;

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyModalOpenButton onClick={ this.onButtonClick.bind(this) } />
                <MyModal ref={ modal => this.myModal = modal } />
            </div>
        );
    }

    private onButtonClick() {
        this.myModal.onButtonClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more or less what I'm trying to do.
But at this point, I would be better to remove the button component and put it in the main renderer...
Is there a way to access to the modal reference (as a main component propery) from the button component ?
To have someting like :
`/* Function in the button component */
onClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
        mainComponent.myModal.display()
    /* Or even this:*/
    myModal.display()
    }`
EDIT: Sorry for the bad indent.....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code in your question doesn't seem right. You have a class `MyModalOpenButton` but in the `App` you're not using it, you're using `SettingsButtons` and `MyModal` for which the code isn't included. The code in the comment is hard to read. Please edit your question with the relevant code and comment here after you changed it, then I'll be able to take a look. Thanks